# How to open a activity when a Qr code is scan?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment, qr-code

I'm developing an Android application using Android Studio and Java. In this app I implemented a Qr code scanner using Scannercode. I have a qr code containing a url. When this specific url is scanned, I would like my application to automatically open another activity. Is it something possible? I tried this code but my application is crashing whenever a qr code is scan.

**CameraFragment.java**

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment {

 String contents;


 private CodeScanner mCodeScanner;

 @Nullable
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                          @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     final Activity activity = getActivity();
     View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);
     CodeScannerView scannerView = root.findViewById(R.id.scanner_view);
     mCodeScanner = new CodeScanner(activity, scannerView);
     mCodeScanner.setDecodeCallback(new DecodeCallback() {
         @Override
         public void onDecoded(@NonNull final Result result) {
             activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {

                     if(Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(result.getText()).equals("https://youtu.be/M2c")) {
                         startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), MilleActivity.class));

                     }

                 }

             });
         }
     });
     scannerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             mCodeScanner.startPreview();
         }
     });
     return root;
 }

 @Override
 public void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     mCodeScanner.startPreview();
 }

 @Override
 public void onPause() {
     mCodeScanner.releaseResources();
     super.onPause();
 }
}
```